# Xamarin Forms Android Frame Renderer and Corner Radius

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

When I create a custom renderer for Xamarin Forms Frame in Android, `CornerRadius` property goes for a toss. No matter what I set it to, it doesn't work. It always draw a rectangle.

Xamarin Forms (Control) -

```
public class MyFrame : Frame
{
}
```

Xamarin Forms (XAML) -

```
<shd:MyFrame WidthRequest="200" HeightRequest="200" CornerRadius="100">
    <shd:MyFrame.Content>
        <Label Text="Hello" TextColor="Black"/>
    </shd:MyFrame.Content>
</shd:MyFrame>
```

Xamarin Android -

```
public class MyFrameRenderer : ViewRenderer<Controls.MyFrame, FrameRenderer>
{
    public MyFrameRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
    {

    }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Controls.MyFrame> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (e.NewElement != null)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

How do I set `CornerRadius` property to give it rounded corners.

Thanks!

**Update**

Neumorphism is design trend, where control have two shades of shadow, dark and light. If you visit [this](https://neumorphism.io/) website you can visualize what I am trying to achieve.

I used Android's 9 patch image to achieve similar effect for a rectangular frame, however, when I tried to provide `CornerRadius` to it, it didn't worked.

Comment: What is your requirement? Frames defaultly provide corner radius. Are you trying to draw circular frame?

Comment: Yes.With a 9 patch image for Android(Neumorphic shadow).

Comment: Hi , could you share the wanted effects of `Frame` your want  , I will check that .

Comment: @GauravMathur Xamarin forms has a nuget package about 9 patch image , you can have a try wtih this  in each iOS or Android platform .https://baskren.github.io/Forms9Patch/guides/Layouts.html#outline--shadow-xaml-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How I did it.

Created a custom renderer for View. With properties for Main color, Dark shadow and Light shadow -

```
public class NeumorphicCircleBackground : View
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty LightColorProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create("LightColor", typeof(Color), typeof(NeumorphicCircleBackground), null);

    public Color LightColor
    {
        get { return (Color)GetValue(LightColorProperty); }
        set { SetValue(LightColorProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty MainColorProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create("MainColor", typeof(Color), typeof(NeumorphicCircleBackground), null);

    public Color MainColor
    {
        get { return (Color)GetValue(MainColorProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MainColorProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty DarkColorProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create("DarkColor", typeof(Color), typeof(NeumorphicCircleBackground), null);

    public Color DarkColor
    {
        get { return (Color)GetValue(DarkColorProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DarkColorProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

And an Android view  -

```
protected override void OnDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        base.OnDraw(canvas);

        var h = canvas.Height;
        var w = canvas.Width;
        var size = Math.Min(h, w);

        float a = 0.1f * size;
        float b = 0.6f * size;
        float x0 = (w - size) / 2;
        float y0 = 0f;

        RectF ovalLight = new RectF();
        RectF ovalMain = new RectF();
        RectF ovalDark = new RectF();
        ovalLight.Set(x0, y0, x0 + b, y0 + b);
        ovalMain.Set(x0 + a, y0 + a, x0 + a + b, y0 + a + b);
        ovalDark.Set(x0 + 2 * a, y0 + 2 * a, x0 + 2 * a + b, y0 + 2 * a + b);

        var r = b / 2;

        var xl = x0 + b / 2;
        var yl = y0 + b / 2;
        var xd = x0 + 2 * a + b / 2;
        var yd = y0 + 2 * a + b / 2;
        var xm = x0 + a + b / 2;
        var ym = y0 + a + b / 2;

        var lightGradient = GetRadialPaint(xl, yl, r, _lightColor);
        var darkGradient = GetRadialPaint(xd, yd, r, _darkColor);
        var mainGradient = new Paint(PaintFlags.AntiAlias) { Color = _mainColor };

        if (_isCircle)
        {
            DrawCircle(canvas, xl, yl, r, lightGradient);
            DrawCircle(canvas, xd, yd, r, darkGradient);
            DrawCircle(canvas, xm, ym, r, mainGradient);
        }
        else
        {
            DrawRoundedRectangle(canvas, ovalLight, 50f, 50f, lightGradient);
            DrawRoundedRectangle(canvas, ovalDark, 50f, 50f, darkGradient);
            DrawRoundedRectangle(canvas, ovalMain, 50f, 50f, mainGradient);
        }
    }
```

I have added further properties for making it a generic Rounded Corner Rectangle as well as a perfect circle. You can modify it the way you want.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

Setting corner radius half of height and width and setting padding to 0 .

```
 <Frame  HeightRequest="100" Padding="0" HorizontalOptions="Center" HasShadow="True" BackgroundColor="Accent" IsClippedToBounds="True" WidthRequest="100" CornerRadius="50">
            <Image Source="yourimage.png" Aspect="AspectFill"></Image>
 </Frame>
```

Comment: In Neumorphic, left and top shadow is of different color and right and bottom shadow are different. I am using 9 patch just for the shadow nothing else. Your solution will only add default material shadow.

Comment: Oh sorry.  For ios you can check this https://www.thewissen.io/playing-around-with-neumorphism-in-xamarin-forms/      and check this too https://github.com/samafshari/RedCorners.Forms

Comment: No problem. iOS is fine, I didn't find any good resource for Android though.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a try with [Forms9Patch](https://baskren.github.io/Forms9Patch/index.html) Nuget Package to implement it in each iOS and Android .Having a look at its [document](https://baskren.github.io/Forms9Patch/guides/Layouts.html#outline--shadow-xaml-example).

```
<StackLayout Padding=" 10">
    <!-- Place new controls here -->
    <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!" 
       HorizontalOptions="Center"
       VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
    <Forms9Patch:Frame Padding="20"
                       HeightRequest="100"
                       WidthRequest="100"
                       OutlineColor="Blue"
                       OutlineWidth="3"
                       OutlineRadius="10"
                       HasShadow="True"
                       BorderRadius="50"
                       BackgroundColor="Gray">
        <!--<Label Text="Forms9Patch.Frame w/ OutlineWidth+OutlineRadius"
               TextColor="White"
               HorizontalOptions="Center"
               VerticalOptions="Center"
               FontSize="14" />-->

    </Forms9Patch:Frame>

</StackLayout>
```

The effect :

[image]

And if want to make image with different shapes , you can use its **Forms9Patch.Image** with [Outline and Shape Properties](https://baskren.github.io/Forms9Patch/guides/Image.html#outline-and-shape-properties)

[image]

Comment: Nice find, but I rolled out my own version. Thank You so much for your help.

Comment: @GauravMathur Glad you find the solution , that's great !